# Problem with contracts being deployed multiple times in Node.JS backend

Tags: javascript, json-rpc, nodejs, ropsten, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I have a Javascript frontend that passes records in a JSON to the backend via Express to be deployed to the blockchain (currently using Rinkeby) with truffle-hdwallet-provider. This appears to work perfectly, but I have a really nasty problem - if I send 19 rows to be deployed, the first 17 or 18 get sent nicely. I see the transaction hash and the receipts come soon after. So far so good, but thereafter, the first records are reposted. I tried playing around with timeout, but all that I managed to do was to stop the server responding after 120 seconds and only 18-19 contracts were deployed.

The relevant front end code is:

```
function importInvoiceData(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    console.log("File Path: "         + input);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
        var newLine=String.fromCharCode(13)+String.fromCharCode(10);
        var invoiceLines=reader.result.split(newLine);
        var numLines = invoiceLines.length;

        console.log("number of invoices: " + numLines);

        var myColumn="";

        var params =[]

        for (var i=1;i<numLines;i++)
            {
            myColumn = invoiceLines[i].split(",");

            var myVendorAddress = myColumn[1];
            var myClientAddress = myColumn[3];
            var myInvoiceID = myColumn[4];
            var myCurrCode = myColumn[5];
            // 25569 = 1/1/1970 start of Unix time
            var myInvoiceDate = (parseInt(myColumn[6])-25569)*86400;
            var myInvoiceAmount = parseInt(myColumn[7])*1000000;
            var myAmountPaid = parseInt(myColumn[8])*1000000;
            var myInvoiceBalance = parseInt(myColumn[9])*1000000;
            var myInsuredAmount = parseInt(myColumn[10])*1000000;
            var myPaymentDays = parseInt(myColumn[11]);
            var myConfirmed = myColumn[12];
            var myInsurerAddress = myColumn[13];                

            console.log("myinvoiceID + myInvoiceBalance: " + myInvoiceID + " " + myInvoiceBalance);

            if (myInvoiceID != "") // This avoids trying to load empty rows
                {

                params[i-1] = { 
                    vendorAddress:  myVendorAddress,
                    clientAddress:  myClientAddress,
                    insurerAddress: myInsurerAddress, 
                    invoiceID:      myInvoiceID,
                    currencyCode:   myCurrCode,
                    invoiceDate:    myInvoiceDate,
                    invoiceAmount:  myInvoiceAmount,
                    amountPaid:     myAmountPaid,
                    invoiceBalance: myInvoiceBalance,
                    insuredAmount:  myInsuredAmount,
                    paymentDays:    myPaymentDays,
                    confirmed:      myConfirmed
                  };

                console.log("params" + JSON.stringify(params[i-1]));              
                } // if (myClientID <> "")
            } // for (var i=1;i<numLines;i++)

            const strParams = JSON.stringify(params);

            console.log("strParams" + strParams);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:80/deploy_invoice", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.send(strParams);

        }; // reader.onloadend = function(){
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    }; // function openInvoiceFile(event) {
```

and the backend code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

// Enable all CORS requests 
app.use(cors());

// enable middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.json());

const Web3 = require("web3");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

require('dotenv').config();
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.INFURA_URL);

var contract    = require("@truffle/contract");

const platformArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Platform.json');
var platformContract = contract(platformArtifacts);
platformContract.setProvider(provider);

const vendorArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Vendor.json');
var vendorContract = contract(vendorArtifacts);
vendorContract.setProvider(provider);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

function convertStringX(myString, len)
    {
    console.log("my String = " + myString);
    var myBuffer = [];
    var temp = Buffer.from(myString);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        // eliminate empty characters (different than spaces which are 0x20)
        if (i < myString.length)
            myBuffer.push(temp[i]);
        else
            myBuffer.push(0x0);         
        } 

    console.log(myBuffer);
    return myBuffer;
    }

var myPlatform;
const platformAddress = "0x...";

async function instantiatePlatform(deployedAddress) {
    myPlatform = await platformContract.at(deployedAddress);
    console.log("myPlatform address " + myPlatform.address);
    }

instantiatePlatform(platformAddress);

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

var whitelist = ['localhost:8080']
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
    var corsOptions;
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    } else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

async function createInvoice(_VendorAddress, _InvoiceID, _InvoiceDate, _PaymentDays, _InvoiceAmount, _InsuredAmount, _AmountPaid, 
        _Confirmed, _InsurerAddress, _ClientAddress, _CurrCode)
    {
    var myVendor = await vendorContract.at(_VendorAddress);

    myVendor.makeInvoice(_InvoiceID, _InvoiceDate, _PaymentDays, _InvoiceAmount, _InsuredAmount, _AmountPaid, 
        _Confirmed, _InsurerAddress, _ClientAddress, _CurrCode, 
        { from:provider.getAddress() })
        .once('transactionHash', function(hash) {
            console.log("TxHash: " + hash);
        }).on('receipt', function(receipt) { console.log("receipt: " + JSON.stringify(receipt)); })
            .then(function(result) {
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    } // async function createInvoice(_InvoiceID, _InvoiceDate, _PaymentDays, _InvoiceAmount, _InsuredAmount, _AmountPaid, _Confirmed, _InsurerAddress, _ClientAddress, _CurrCode)

app.post('/deploy_invoice', (req, res) => {

    var myInput=req.body;
    console.log("myInput "+ myInput.length+ " " +myInput[0].invoiceID);

    for (i=0;i<myInput.length;i++)  
        {
        // Only add record if invoice is non-empty
        if (myInput[i].invoiceID != null && myInput[i].invoiceID != "")
            {
            var myVendorAddress = myInput[i].vendorAddress;
            var myClientAddress = myInput[i].clientAddress;
            var myInsurerAddress = myInput[i].insurerAddress;
            var myInvoiceID = myInput[i].invoiceID;
            myInvoiceID = convertStringX(myInvoiceID, 16);
            console.log("myInvoiceID "+ myInvoiceID);
            var myCurrCode = myInput[i].currencyCode;
            myCurrCode = convertStringX(myCurrCode, 3);
            console.log("myCurrCode "+ myCurrCode);
            var myInvoiceDate = myInput[i].invoiceDate;
            console.log("myInvoiceDate "+ myInvoiceDate);
            var myInvoiceAmount = myInput[i].insuredAmount;
            console.log("myInvoiceAmount "+ myInvoiceAmount);
            var myAmountPaid = myInput[i].amountPaid;
            console.log("myAmountPaid "+ myAmountPaid);
            var myInvoiceBalance = myInput[i].invoiceBalance;
            console.log("myInvoiceBalance "+ myInvoiceBalance);
            var myInsuredAmount = myInput[i].insuredAmount;
            console.log("myInsuredAmount "+ myInsuredAmount);
            var myPaymentDays = myInput[i].paymentDays;
            console.log("myPaymentDays "+ myPaymentDays);
            var myConfirmed = myInput[i].confirmed;
            myConfirmed = convertStringX(myConfirmed, 1);
            console.log("myConfirmed "+ myConfirmed);

            createInvoice(myVendorAddress, myInvoiceID, myInvoiceDate, myPaymentDays, myInvoiceAmount, myInsuredAmount, myAmountPaid, 
                myConfirmed, myInsurerAddress, myClientAddress, myCurrCode);
            }
        }

        // This was the missing link
        res.send("Data received!");

    });

const port = 80;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

The problem I am sure has to with the asynchronous nature of the call to the blockchain, but I quite new to node and HTTP requests.

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The answer is really simple, but maybe I can help someone else by sharing the solution.

I did not send back a receipt of the request from the client. I added the line:

```
res.send("Data received!");
```

I put it just before the end of the POST after looping through all the records received. I have also updated the code above to reflect this. Easy when you know how!